Looking for a specific paranormal movie title about a poltergeist
Filmed within the last five years? 
English - Filmed in the US
Set in modern times - movie takes place over only ONE night after she come home from work.
It opens with a woman doing a tarot reading - in a very small storefront -
though that's not integral to the film. Just that she is one unless maybe it follows her from the reading?
She's in her late 20's (?) I believe dark blonde hair. I could be wrong about that but she's NOT a model type. 
Woman goes home to house - (new townhouse?) and it's full of artifacts her husband collected before he died (young). Masks, tribal statues such.
She spends a lot of time video chatting with her beautiful black friend - they "call" each other back and forth. 
During the film things fly off the shelves and in the kitchen. Poltergeist activity thru the entire film.
Very ominous and creepy.
There is a storage room in the house (upstairs) with artwork that creeps her out. Doors fly open - etc. She finds a big (doll?) in the laundry room that was in that cold room.  Energy rushes out at her. 
I think I remember her friend dying?
This movie is scary as hell to me because it's the things you CAN'T see that freak me out!  
Wasn't a huge budget film and it's not on any "list of scary movies..." that I can find. 
I think I rented it off the "new" release wall in my now defunct video store! So it had to be within the last five years - when I moved here - well - unless they were lying!

I FOUND IT!  I scrolled through my old FB posts where I had posted it a LONG time ago!  I couldn't believe it had such a low rating - sure there are some problem spots but it scared the heck out of me,  THE VISITANT        https://horrorpedia.com/2015/09/17/the-visitant-paranormal-encounter-2014/

I was wrong on some details: She is in her 30's, a redhead, and her best friend is Asian.  Sorry about that!  It's free on youtube right now.
